# Using vbscript to run an function in ms access 2007

Tags: vba, ms-access, vbscript

I have a backend database protected with password. I want to run an vbscript to compact and repair the database can you please help me to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SO is not inteded as a "give me ze code" platform

Comment: Do it by yourself before asking

Comment: VBScript isn't VBA, are you *sure* you want to do this with VBScript?

Comment: See this, there's an example using VBScript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503736/access-compact-and-repair-programatically

Comment: @KostasK. that's VBA. VBScript doesn't have an `As` keyword :)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - Kostas mentions there's a VBScript example in his question link - that specific example link is https://stackoverflow.com/a/3517111/2419128

Comment: @dbmitch ah, missed it. So there's fun for everyone then! =)

Comment: @madrac thnx for your valuable "comment"