Display Document Tabs setting MS Access VBA
In a MS Access DB - To display forms in tabs instead of overlapping windows, I am aware of the method in Access Options - Current Database - Display Document Tabs. When you switch this, you are prompted to exit and reenter the db for it to take effect.
Is there any known way to do this at run-time with VBA code?

CurrentDb.Properties("UseMDIMode").Value = 1 resp.  CurrentDb.Properties("UseMDIMode").Value = 0 will switch the setting but you still have to close and re-open the database for the changes to take effect.

Why would you want to do this? Run Compact & Repair to effect change https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460129/ms-access-how-to-compact-current-database-in-vba

Not at all clear why you would need this.  The setting once set is per database, and thus once set, there should be no need further mess with this setting.

My reason is when I push a front-end DB out to users, I don't like tabs in it and when I develop, I like the tabs. And I am working on a switch to take me in a dev mode where I don't have to keep manually setting these little things each time. so thus, if I can have one button to switch to my dev mode where I see tabs, ribbon, switch my data to test server etc it just makes it a bit easier on me. Thanks.

Ok so something I have noticed about the solution above using the currentdb properties.  It sets the document window option to either overlapping or tabbed documents which is what I asked. But from further investigation what I actually am looking for is to set the option to display document tabs or not while keeping the Document window option set to tabbed documents. Any ideas?

Ok never mind I found it. For anyone interested it is CurrentDb.Properties("ShowDocumentTabs")=True or CurrentDb.Properties("ShowDocumentTabs")=False
